# why i can't start orbd service CORBA IIOP?

Tags: java, windows, corba

why i can't start orbd service CORBA IIOP?

C:>start orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050

C:>orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050

Failed to start ORBD because of an Internal Exception.
Possible Causes:
1. Specified ORBInitialPort or ORBActivationPort is already in use
2. No Write Permission to write orb.db

C:>

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate the two possible causes it lists:

1) Port already in use: There could be another application that is listening on this port.  Try running netstat -na at a command prompt and see if this is the case.  The other possible explanation for a port problem here is that the port is < 1024, meaning that it's a privileged port, you might have permissions issues with this.  Try it with a port > 1024.

2) No Write Permission to orb.db: The orbd program writes a log file called orb.db that it uses to recover state if it is restarted.  The default behavior is to store this file in the same directory as the orbd executable.  If you do not have write permission to the directory that the orbd.exe file is in, then you will get this error.  If this is the case, use the -deafultdb option to specify a different directory that you can write to.  See here: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/idl/orbd.html

Answer (score 1):

What errors did you get?if you did not get any error it means the orbd started.
i use 1050 on different computers ,it did not work on some of them.try 1049 or 777.

Answer (score 0):

you must to lauch the orbd in another place, because you have not permissions in the C:\

you can to make an directory 
C:\ORB_DIRECTORY and so:

C:>mkdir ORB_DIRECTORY

C:>cd ORB_DIRECTORY

C:\ORB_DIRECTORY>orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050

I'm sorry my English, but I'm a Colombian